# What does numpy.concatenate do with a single argument?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have read about [concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html). But, did not see the function taking a single list as input.It must have two lists as input.

Consider the following statement in a program that I want to execute

> row = np.concatenate(row, 1)

What is concatenate doing here? It is taking only one list named *row*.

Comment: The first argument is a `sequence`, `(a1, a2, ...)`.  That's one list, tuple, or even array (treated as a list of arrays)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have seen it most often used like this:

```
c = np.concatenate([a, b])
```

but you can of course also do:

```
ab = [a, b]
c = np.concatenate(ab)
```

Look at `row` before and after concatenating to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `np.concatenate` is supposed to be a sequence of objects (think vectors or matrices). The second argument is the axis along which the concatenation is to be performed. See `help(np.concatenate)` for the full docstring.

For your command to be valid, the objects in the `row` sequence must have at least a 0th and a 1st dimension. This would typically be a matrix, but the name `row` is suggestive of a set of row vectors that have dimension `[0, d]`.

If you concatenate `n` vectors of shape `[0, d]` along the 1st dimension, this will result in an object of shape `[0, n*d]`. Which is a very long row vector.